# send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: error-handling, discord.py

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = bot.get_channel('757774774075261051')
    if message.guild is None and message.author != bot.user:
        await message.channel.send(channel, message.content)
    await bot.process_commands(message)
```

for some reason i get this error any help?

Error:

```
    await message.channel.send(channel, message.content)
TypeError: send() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 1):

With the *new* (after v1.0) [`Messageable.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=send#discord.abc.Messageable.send) method, you don't need the channel as argument anymore so you just have to write:

```py
await message.channel.send(message.content)
```

If you want to know what changed between `discord.py` (before v1.0) and `discord.py rewrite` (after v1.0), [here's a link](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/migrating.html).